# Drawing using Graphics in Java

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I have a Graphics question. I'm trying to draw an image in a Frame and I'm having some issue. I want to know what's the best approach to successfully do what I want to do. 
I will show my 3 classes. The Main class create the Menu. Once Matchmaking button is press, it create the Board object and call Main.draw to paint all it's component (only Board for now). The picture only sometime appear so it make me realise my code isn't probably setup the right way. THANKS!!!

MAIN CLASS

```
                import java.awt.Graphics;
                public class Main 
            {
                public static Board theBoard;

                public static void main(String[] args) 
                {
                    new Menu("Main Menu").setVisible(true); 
                }

                public static void draw(Graphics painter)
                {
                    theBoard.draw(painter);
                }
            }
```

MENU CLASS

```
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;

    public class Menu extends JFrame implements ActionListener
    {
        //Jpanel
        JPanel pnlButton = new JPanel();
        //Buttons
        JButton btnMatchmaking = new JButton("Matchmaking");
        JButton btnExit = new JButton("Exit");
        JButton btnProfile = new JButton("Profile");
        JButton btnOption = new JButton("Options");

        public Menu(String s) 
        {        
            super("Bu$ted: " + s);  
            btnExit.addActionListener(this);
            btnMatchmaking.addActionListener(this);
            //JPanel setting
            pnlButton.add(btnMatchmaking);
            pnlButton.add(btnProfile);
            pnlButton.add(btnOption);
            pnlButton.add(btnExit);
            pnlButton.setVisible(true);

            //The winddow options
            super.setLocation(0,0); //A remplacer par des dimension variables
            super.setSize(600, 500);    //A remplacer par des dimension variables
            super.setResizable(false);
            super.setVisible(true);
            super.add(pnlButton);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        }

        //Handle action events.
        //@param evt
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) 
        { 
            if(evt.getSource() == btnMatchmaking)
            {
                super.remove(pnlButton);   
                Main.theBoard = new Board("TestBoard");
                super.add(Main.theBoard);
                super.setSize(Main.theBoard.boardSize);      
                Main.draw(super.getGraphics()); 


            }
            if(evt.getSource() == btnExit)
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
```

BOARD CLASS

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Board extends JPanel
{
    BufferedImage boardImage;
    int width;
    int height;
    Dimension boardSize;

    public Board (String boardName)
    {
        boardImage = loadBoard(boardName);
        width=boardImage.getWidth();
        height=boardImage.getHeight();
        boardSize = new Dimension(width,height);
        this.setVisible(true);
        System.out.println("The board is setup.");
    }

    private BufferedImage loadBoard (String boardName)
    {
        BufferedImage img = null;
        try 
        {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File("Components/"+boardName+".png"));
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            System.out.println("The board image couldn't be loaded.");
        }
        return img;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics painter)
    {
        painter.drawImage(boardImage, 0, 0, null);
        System.out.println("The board image was painted.");
    }
}
```

Comment: You **should not** draw anywhere but `paint()` (basically, don't do that). Read [Getting Started with Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/start/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

The recommended approach is to override the `paintComponent` of your `Board` class and let the paint system handel it...

See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Perfoming Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

Comment: So, I shouldn't use my homebrew Draw() method but use the paintCOmponent? I knew there was something like this lol, but couldn't remember (been a couple years before I programmed haha) Thanks for quick answer bro!

Comment: @P4ndaH3ro: if MadProgrammer's reply answered your question then please consider accepting it.